# Updating a URL by adding a value of 1

Tags: javascript

So let's say the URL I have is

`"mywebsite.com/file/100/"`

What I want is for it to be updated to

`"mywebsite.com/file/101/"`

`"mywebsite.com/file/102/"`

(and so on...)

when the keyword cannot be found.

```
init();

function init()
{
    searchWord("key word");
}

function searchWord(word)
{
   var pageResults = document.body.innerHTML.match(word);
   if(pageResults)
   {
       alert("word found");
   } else {
   }
}
```

Right now my script searches for a key term, and what I need is for the page to be updated by a value of 1 (100 to 101 to 102 etc) when the keyword cannot be found.

I am a noob a Javascript, none of this code is mine. I just need help developing it. I have searched around for a while, but I can't find much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this gets points for elegance.

- Split the url into segments
- Dispose of empty segment caused by trailing "/" if present.
- If the last segment is numeric, replace it with its numeric value + 1.
- Join the segments back into a string.
- (If you want the trailing slash you can re-add it.)

Code

```
var url = "mywebsite.com/file/100/"
var segments = url.split("/");
while(segments[segments.length-1]==""){
  segments.pop();
}
var lastSegment = segments[segments.length-1];
if(!isNaN(lastSegment)){
    segments[segments.length-1] = (parseInt(lastSegment)+1).toString();
}
updatedUrl = segments.join("/");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Here is my current script in a paste http://pastebin.com/hnxvXKxR it seems to do nothing but reload the page w/o adding a value of 1 to the end of the URL (100 to 101 to 102 etc). Can you see anything that is wrong? I've tried a few things but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

One liner just for fun.

```
var url = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.split('/').map(function(sgmt){return (sgmt != '' && !isNaN(sgmt)) ? parseInt(sgmt)+1 : sgmt}).join('/');
```

You may want to omit the `window.location.hostname` to use relative url paths instead. The next piece first splits the url at the `/` and then uses the `.map()` method on the new array. The function that gets passed looks for non-blank and numerical sections of the url. If it finds it, it adds 1. When finished, it makes the array a string again (with the new number in the url) using the `.join()` method.